# redirect unit test on component

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, components

I want to do unit-testing for redirect on Component.

**redirectComponent.php**

```
 public function redirect(){
   $controller = $this->_Collection -> getController();
   $controller->redirect('https://test.com');
 }
```

But I write this code, not show nothing

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : portal
Path: **
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
PHPUnit 3.7.37 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

How can I test redirect on component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock the redirect method of the controller object.

Comment: Thanks! I can do with mock.